# meaning of "the singletons of $\Gamma$ are a basis for $\Gamma$"

Tags: descriptive-set-theory

In a set of notes for the Cabal Seminar a theorem is attributed to Moschovakis which includes the statement that for certain pointclasses $\Gamma$ the singletons of $\Gamma$ are a basis for $\Gamma$. I've been having difficulty locating a definition of a basis for a pointclass and would appreciate any help.

Comment: could you link those notes if they are available online?

Comment: I think this is supposed to mean that every nonempty set in class $\Gamma$ contains ($\supseteq$) a singleton in class $\Gamma$. But it could also conceivably mean that every nonempty set in class $\Gamma$ contains ($\ni$) a real in class $\Gamma$. This “basis” terminology is abominable, and totally at odds with the meaning of “basis” in other parts of mathematics; but the general idea is that $B$ being a “basis” for $P$ means $(\exists x.(P(x))) \Rightarrow (\exists x\in B.(P(x)))$.

Comment: I'm afraid I only have a hardback copy of the notes. I appreciate Gro-Tsen's discussion.